# How can I connect my vertices and get rid of the red normals?

Tags: vertices

I'm at the unwrapping stage of my plane and I can't unwrap my plane wing on the simple fact that the normals are red and my vertices will not join. Is there any way that I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/merge.html

Comment: The red you're seeing is actually the reverse sides of the mesh seen through the gap between the wing and body. It's not because the normals are inverted. If they are one object, follow the link @FFeller points you to, otherwise join the objects with Ctrl-J and then merge the verts.